# Personalization targeting Android only

Tags: personalization

I have (2) hero components, and would like to display a hero to those users who are on an android (mobile web).

The "device" personalization rules I'm using don't seem to be working properly. I found a hefty Excel document a couple of weeks ago (called "Sitecore Device Detection Full List of Parameters") that was very helpful, which contained the content for the "specific value" in the rule. (from https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/using-device-detection.html)

Here are the (3) rules I have in place (note that I have 3 listed currently, in my attempt to target sole android users)

All (3) are under "Device" rule section:

`where the device operating system contains Android`

`or where the device operating system contains Google`

`or where the device vendor contains Google`

There really should only be (1) rule applied, the other (2) I added in hopes of eventually finding which (1) to use.

Another issue is I even removed the (3) rules listed above, and added this one:

`where device type is one of Smartphone`

in hopes of at least targeting only mobile web, but that did not work either.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So....for whatever reason, GeoIP isn't configured on our CM server (this may be done by design, or it may be a Sitecore instance rule). Once I published this to production, it is working as expected.

The rule I used was:

`where the device operating system contains Android`

Comment: No xConnect/Geo IP runs on CM be design.